# Android Studio gives me Execution failed for task ':library:proguardRelease' error after updating to Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, build.gradle

I updated my Android Studio to 1.0.1. I followed this tutorial http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0 and changed from `runProguard`  to `minifyEnabled true`. I also changed it in my library project. When I tried to compile it gave me `Error:Execution failed for task ':> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ProjectName\library\proguard-rules.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`. I researched for that and I found a solution. I added blank `proguard-rules.txt` file into that folder. After trying to compile, it gave me even more errors. The main error now was that it `cannot find symbol class PageIndicator`, which is my library's class. I don't even know what can I do for that.

My project's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.miesto.meniu"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.0@aar'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-xml:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services'
    }
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services'
    }
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

My library's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Add appropriate rules to `proguard-android.txt` to tell ProGuard to `-keep` your public API of your library.

Comment: proguard-android.txt which is located here C:\sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt ? How can I do it?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I grabbed the wrong filename. I meant your `proguard-rules.txt` that you added to your project. My apologies for my mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure do I have to write like this: `-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.**`?

Comment: That would probably work, with one or more such lines indicating what classes you cannot afford to have renamed or removed.

Comment: Well, I added these lines: 
`-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.PageIndicator
-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter
-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator`
But now I am getting 2 strange errors: 1. cannot find symbol method setViewPager(ViewPager) and 2. Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. What's wrong now?

Comment: Hi, But in my case i am trying to release signed apk with existing keystore of eclipse, it is saying like proguard-rules.txt file not found on specified path. what shall i do? Thanks for prompt reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem when I deleted my library and added it again.

Comment: Hi, But in my case i am trying to release signed apk with existing keystore of eclipse, it is saying like proguard-rules.txt file not found on specified path. what shall i do? Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: First of all, try to put blank proguard-rules.txt into specified location.